# Why did James R. Munkres write "If $a \in Y$" in the proof of the theorem 16.4 on p.91 in "Topology 2nd Edition"?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I am reading "Topology 2nd Edition" by James R. Munkres.
In the proof of the theorem 16.4 on p.91, Munkres wrote:
"If $a\in Y$, then $$(a,+\infty)\cap Y=\{x \mid x \in Y \text{ and } x > a\};"$$

I think the following equality holds even if $a \notin Y$. $$(a,+\infty)\cap Y=\{x \mid x \in Y \text{ and } x > a\}.$$

Why did Munkres write "If $a\in Y$,".
[image]

Comment: Correct... but it is only not very clearly phrased. It must be: "Consider the ray... What is its intersection with $Y$, i.e. the set $(a,+∞) \cap Y = \{ x \mid x∈Y \text {  and  } x>a \}$ ?" Then the author "compute" this set, considering two cases : (i) $a \in Y$, and (ii) $a \notin Y$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you very much for your comment.